# [: -!eq: binary operator expected

Tags: bash

I have an issue with this Below Code 
getting an error called :

```
[: -!eq: binary operator expected]
```

How do I fix this error

```
RC=$?
if [ $RC -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo  File: $j Deletion Successfull >> $_Main/Status"_"$_date
else
    echo File: $j Deletion Failed >> $_Main/Status"_"$_date
fi
```

Comment: Try using `"$RC"` in case it's set to an empty string.

Comment: The `!` in the error message is weird, you might have an invisible char between the dash and the eq ; I'd rewrite the whole `if [ "$RC" -eq 0 ]; then` by hand

Comment: @Shawn not working .... "$RC"

Comment: Try adding `set -x` just before it, and see what the shell thinks is going on. (If necessary, add the output to your question in code format so it's readable.) BTW, have you changed `IFS`?

Comment: Can you please try adding the exit status directly in the if condition.

`if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then`

Comment: Paste your script into shellcheck.net

Comment: Why use `command ; RC=$? ; if [ $RC -eq 0 ]` instead of just `if command`?

Answer (score 2):

The source of the error: [: –le: binary operator expected might be that you are using the unicode version of "–" instead of the regular "-".

Check your keyboard settings / mappings and try to use the normal "-".

Answer (score 2):

You code is running perfectly well. However, if i change it like that :

```
#!/bin/sh

RC=$?
if [ $RC eq 0 ]; then
    echo  File:
else
    echo File:
fi
```

I got the same error :

```
./test.sh: line 4: [: eq: binary operator expected
File:
```

This means you should check that you are using -eq and not anything else. The problem is clearly located into your condition.

In your case, seems that you tried to negate the equals condition with a `!`. This clearly won't work.

Comment: `! [ $RC -eq 0 ]` would be the correct syntax for a negation test . Good luck to all.